# Is it ok to store peanut oil in the container it came in after being used?

Tags: frying, oil, storage

I am starting to get into frying again.  I was wondering if it is ok to store the oil after it has cooled down in its original container or if there is a better option for storage.

Comment: I typically gather up the oil after it's cooled down, and pour it bit-by-bit through a funnel + coffee filter into it's original container.

Comment: It would be helpful to know more about the actual container. Is it metal, plastic or glass? A link to the actual product (in the same container) would be great.

Comment: Why would it not be safe? What are you concerned about?

Answer (score 1):

If the container is labelled with one of the standard logos that mark an unconditionally food safe container, there should be no concern: Used peanut oil is still food, so a container specified to deal with food should deal with it too.

If not, assume that the container has only been designed to be safe with the exact, unaltered ingredient shipped in it (oil and plastic chemistry can get very complicated, some edible oils WILL dissolve some plastics).

The best option will always be an airtight, food safe, glass, stored in the dark container well filled.